# Extend highcharts renderer symbols to have plus sign

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

How can I extend highcharts renderer symbols library to include a "Plus" sign.

Comment: use an image http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.marker.symbol

Comment: Demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

API Reference of [plotOptions.series.marker.symbol](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.symbol)

> symbol: String
>
> A predefined shape or symbol for the marker. When null, the symbol is
>   pulled from options.symbols. Other possible values are "circle",
>   "square", "diamond", "triangle" and "triangle-down".
>
> Additionally, the URL to a graphic can be given on this form:
>   "url(graphic.png)". Note that for the image to be applied to exported
>   charts, its URL needs to be accessible by the export server.
>
> Custom callbacks for symbol path generation can also be added to
>   Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols. The callback is then used by
>   its method name, as shown in the demo.

Like in the last paragraph above, we would define the symbol path for creating a plus. Here is what the documentaion says about [Renderer.path](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path)

> Add a path based on SVG's path commands. In SVG capable browsers all
>   path commands are supported, but in VML only a subset is supported:
>   absolute moveTo (M), absolute lineTo (L), absolute curveTo (C) and
>   close (Z).

And this is how the co-ordinate system would look like, the actual point at the centre of a w x h box with its top-left corner placed at (x,y) & y increasing as we move downwards and x increasing as we move towards the right.

[image]

Here is how you would do a plus

```
// Define a custom symbol path
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.plus = function (x, y, w, h) {
    return ['M', x, y + h / 2, 'L', x + w, y + h / 2, 'M', x + w / 2, y, 'L', x + w / 2, y + h, 'z'];
};
if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.plus = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.plus;
}
```

To explain the array in words

1. **`'M', x, y + h / 2`:** We move our pen to pt. A (x,y+h/2)
2. **`'L', x + w, y + h / 2:`** We draw a line from the current position to pt. B (x+w,y+h/2). This draws the horizontal line of the plus from A <-> B
3. **`'M', x + w / 2, y:`** We now move the pen to pt. C (x+w/2,y), notice that moving the pen does not create any graphic or line
4. **`'L', x + w / 2, y + h:`** We now draw a line from current position to pt. D(x+w/2,y+h). This draws the vertical line of the plus C <-> D
5. **`'z':`** We close the renderer/pen

[Custom Marker Symbol @jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/qtdzo07o/)

Comment: thanks man. Can you explain how this works? I need a button symbol as well. 3 dots something like  ...

Comment: @JabranSaeed added explanation to the answer

Comment: This was so incredibly useful!  Thank you very much for adding such a detailed description and adding the image.

Comment: You are most welcome @Aaron Thanks for the appreciation, helps to keep going ;)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer only gives a single line per cross. I wanted a fully filled in plus sign. Here is the code to instead do that:

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.plus = function (x, y, w, h) {
    return [
        'M', x, y + (5 * h) / 8,
        'L', x, y + (3 * h) / 8,
        'L', x + (3 * w) / 8, y + (3 * h) / 8,
        'L', x + (3 * w) / 8, y,
        'L', x + (5 * w) / 8, y,
        'L', x + (5 * w) / 8, y + (3 * h) / 8,
        'L', x + w, y + (3 * h) / 8,
        'L', x + w, y + (5 * h) / 8,
        'L', x + (5 * w) / 8, y + (5 * h) / 8,
        'L', x + (5 * w) / 8, y + h,
        'L', x + (3 * w) / 8, y + h,
        'L', x + (3 * w) / 8, y + (5 * h) / 8,
        'L', x, y + (5 * h) / 8,
        'z'
    ];
};
if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.plus = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.plus;
}
```

This will produce a plus at 25% width for each bar.