# Draw symbols between bars in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to draw a symbol between bars as shown in image
Is is possible in highcharts?

[image]

Comment: everything possible just show me the code

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 https://plnkr.co/edit/J0BlYGnp5Mi796HwEtHf

Comment: Since others are on the answer, I am just going to ask: Why? The order of the bars is already implied in the chart, and adding an extraneous repeating symbol to indicate it just adds visual clutter that takes focus away from the actual data being plotted. Is there some greater purpose that they will serve that isn't evident in the example?

Comment: @jlbriggs same question I asked to the designers. :P and they were like its a requirement, you have to implement it :(

Comment: @Kenny ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I guess that's the way it goes sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a triangle as a custom shape, then use that shape and set it as a scatter point (or fixed position, or other options). Here is a good answer regarding creating shapes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27591082/8376046

**Creating a custom triangle shape:**

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.supertri = function(x, y, w, h) {
  return ['M', x + w/2, y - h,
    'l', w, h,
    's', w * 1.1, h * 0.9, w * 0.1,  h * 1.8,
    'l', -w , h,
    's', -w * 2.0, h * 2.3,  -w * 1.8,  -h * 0.5,
    'l', w * 0, -h * 3.4,
    's', -w * 0.1,  -h * 2.0,  w * 1.5, -h * 0.1,
    'z'
  ];
};
if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
  Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.supertri = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.supertri;
}
```

**Creating a fake series to use this shape:**

```
series: [
  ...
  ,{
    type: 'scatter',
    pointStart: 0.5,
    data: [20,20,20],
    marker: {
      symbol: 'supertri',
      radius: 2,
      fillColor: 'black'
    },
    showInLegend: false,
    enableMouseTracking: false
}]
```

```js
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.supertri = function(x, y, w, h) {
    return ['M', x + w/2, y - h,
      'l', w, h,
      's', w * 1.1, h * 0.9, w * 0.1,  h * 1.8,
      'l', -w , h,
      's', -w * 2.0, h * 2.3,  -w * 1.8,  -h * 0.5,
      'l', w * 0, -h * 3.4,
      's', -w * 0.1,  -h * 2.0,  w * 1.5, -h * 0.1,
      'z'
    ];
  };
  if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.supertri = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.supertri;
  }
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'column',
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'axis title',
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
          "-webkit-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
          "-moz-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
          "-o-transform": "rotate(90deg)"
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [80, 40, 20, 10],
      }, {
       type: 'scatter',
        pointStart: 0.5,
        data: [20,20,20],
        marker: {
          symbol: 'supertri',
          radius: 2,
          fillColor: 'black'
        },
        showInLegend: false,
        enableMouseTracking: false
      }]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/L05xzzka/4/