# SVGRenderer function

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have no experience using `SVG`. I'm trying to add an icon via the `SVGRenderer` function but I'm not able to change some properties of the icon. I was able to recreate the icon via the `path` but I can't change `height` or `width` of the icon, I want to make it smaller.

I'm using `react-highcharts` wrapper. This is the function call:

```js
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.stockTools = function() {
      var path = [
        "M22.7 19l-9.1-9.1c.9-2.3.4-5-1.5-6.9-2-2-5-2.4-7.4-1.3L9 6 6 9 1.6 4.7C.4 7.1.9 10.1 2.9 12.1c1.9 1.9 4.6 2.4 6.9 1.5l9.1 9.1c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l2.3-2.3c.5-.4.5-1.1.1-1.4z"
      ];
      return path;
    };
```

[Here](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) is documentation for that function and [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/costume-icon-4m5v2?file=/src/CustomGUIChart.js:1089-1388) a live demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that it is impossible to achieve it in this way.

**Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols** this function returns a path. Each of these values in the array means the next position where the line should be drawn - in really basic words.

Check this example to see what I am talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c38ofw5h/

for `['M', 0, 0 ]` it's like {x: 0, y: 0} , so starts points, next `['L', 100, 100]` it's like the drawn line to {x: 100, y: 100}. You pasted a complicated array of coordinates to drawn it, with 'fixed height'.

It is also very good explained here: [Extend highcharts renderer symbols to have plus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542928/extend-highcharts-renderer-symbols-to-have-plus-sign/27591082#27591082)

Of course, the SVG element could be customized. But as an HTML element. It is very good explained here: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

So, with the above information, I think that a better approach is to create a custom label as an HTML element.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/costume-icon-mfg7z

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.render

Comment: Is it possible to make icon position fixed relative to right side instead of left side? When you click the tool button the menu expansion forces the buton to overlap other menu itens.

Comment: @BernardoMarques You can attach the symbol to some other elements, like here: https://codesandbox.io/s/costume-icon-h9iqi

Comment: Thanks, that worked as expected. The only thing I can't get to work is the color, the .css() call doesn't affect icon color, I have also tried incolor call on svg element but it also didn't work.

Comment: @BernardoMarques you can set the fill attribute in the HTML inline styling. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/costume-icon-nqjx0